# Integration testing transaction outputs on the @InitiatedBy side post transaction finality

Tags: corda

I have a situation where I have an `@InitiatingFlow`, called ProposeMemberFlow, and a corresponding `@InitiatedBy` ProposeMemberFlowResponder.  I would like include in my integration test something that tests that the responder has one of the transaction output states post the FinalityFlow sub flow having been kicked off by the initiating flow.

I naively called `waitForLedgerCommit` in the responding flow, post responding to the CollectSignaturesFlow, but I'm finding that the initiating flow finishes before the responding flow does - presumably the latter is waiting for the vault update.

I'm integration testing through a CordaService - is "the corda way" to use `expectEvents` to wait for `VaultUpdate`s so that I then know when it's safe to test against the CordaService?  Much like [here](https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-integration-testing.html)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't heard of integration testing via a `CordaService`. Generally, you would write integration tests using the node driver.

Here's an example: https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-kotlin/blob/release-V2/cordapp/src/integrationTest/kotlin/com/template/DriverBasedTest.kt

This piece of code starts a set of nodes, then uses RPC to check some conditions of the node.

In your case, you'd want to use the following set of RPC operations in the node driver:

- `CordaRPCOps.startFlowDynamic` on node A's RPC handle to run the `ProposeMemberFlow`
- `CordaRPCOps.vaultQueryBy` on node B's RPC handle to check that the correct state has been written to the vault

Another option would be to use the mock network (e.g. https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example/blob/release-V2/kotlin-source/src/test/kotlin/com/example/flow/IOUFlowTests.kt). You could argue that this isn't an integration test, since you are running mock nodes instead of real nodes. However, the mock nodes are just another implementation of the `AbstractNode` interface, and should behave like normal nodes for the purposes of testing.

Comment: Thanks Joel :-)  With Integration Tests I like to test from the entry points to the system.  In my case that's a (Braid based) CordaService. So I didn't really want to start at the flow level.  That said I asked for "The Corda Way" and your answer rather neatly summarises that.  So thanks v. much for taking the time to answer :-)